# Cannot restart apache after certificate replacement

Tags: ssl-certificate, apache2

After accidentally letting our certificate expire, I generated a new private key and CSR with the command:

```
openssl req -new -keyout digitalcollections_ohsu_edu.key -out digitalcollections_ohsu_edu.csr
```

Private key had a passphase.

After installing everything, the server won't come up. Error in the logs is:

```
Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key digitalcollections.ohsu.edu:443:0, check /etc/ssl/private/digitalcollections_ohsu_edu.key
```

Permissions on all files are good, the key is definitely the one used for the CSR, passphrase is correct (if I intentionally get it wrong, that appears in the logs).

Any idea where I should look?

Comment: What are the rest of the errors?

Comment: That was the only one -- literally a single line. 

However, I figured out what was going on. I need an Intermediate/Root cert but had a Root/Intermediate cert in place. Once I corrected that, everything started working.

Once I swapped that out, everything worked fine.

Comment: In that case, I propose you write an answer to your own question explaining just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be caused by my downloading the wrong cert.

If there's a moral to the story, don't trust cert names on the machine. I downloaded a Root/Intermediate cert rather than the Intermediate/Root one I needed because the default name of the former matched the file on the machine and the latter did not.

Once I downloaded the correct cert everything worked fine.